# A more appropriate phrase regarding a thesis than "putting forward"?

Tags: phrase-requests, academia

Do I...

- "put forward a thesis"?
- "propose a thesis"?
- "put a thesis forward"?
- "promote a thesis"?
- "promote the thesis of X"?
- "present a thesis"?
- "raise a thesis"?
- "postulate"/"theorize"/"speculate"/"suggest", without using the actual word "thesis"?
- something else?

Note: I'm not talking about a document or an essay which you might submit, but about a theoretical construction, a set of interrelated ideas, etc.

Comment: Flaunt, sport, front, wield, bust out with...

"Lemmee wag this thesis of mine at you..." Just kidding- it's an interesting question.

Comment: *Submit* seems to be the usual way of expressing this. If you want to be more original, you could also consider *proffer*.

Comment: @Hans Adler: I don't understand why no-one has asked OP to disambiguate which of the two primary senses of ***thesis*** he's asking about, since they have such *huge* implications for the verb likely to be used. I must tell you that ***proffer*** doesn't even figure in the top ten - and that's after excluding the two that are almost exclusively reserved for the formal academic process. (Nor do any of bobro's suggestions, but I expect that surprises no-one! :)

Comment: You left out a *p* word: *purport*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Good point about the ambiguity. Apparently all previous respondents automatically read it one way or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[propound](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+propound&oq=define+propound)

put forward (an idea or theory) for consideration by others.

Along with Mysti Sinha, I recommend *propound,* which FumbleFingers' research also unearths.

I also like *pose,* especially because it's not so commonly used with *thesis, theory, hypothesis,* etc.

[pose](http://i.word.com/idictionary/pose)

to set forth or offer for attention or consideration {let me *pose* a question}

Answer (score 6):

My opinion-

> - [propound](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/) a thesis
> - present a thesis

When you propound an idea, you put it forward.
(vocabulary.com)

Answer (score 6):

I would use the word *[submit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/submit)*:

> 3.0 [WITH OBJECT] Present (a proposal, application, or other document) to a person or body for consideration or judgement:
>   *the panel’s report was submitted to a parliamentary committee*
>
> 3.1 [WITH CLAUSE] (Especially in judicial contexts) suggest; argue:

*I **submit** my thesis with compelling arguments for peer review.*

Comment: Sorry, I am specifically not submitting it to anyone...

Comment: LOL @einpoklum! Are you just going to keep this thesis to yourself and not **share** it with anyone?

Comment: I like Propose the best

Comment: Submit seems to be the formal word, but it good in my ear for the informal presentation of  any proposition.

Comment: @MorganHorse: It's not in any physical form. Suppose I intend it to come up in a spirited discussion...

Comment: Submit is a fine word whether one wants to use it to mean put forward for consideration, evaluation, discussion, or approval, and to anyone, specific or general, and in the form of a document or speech, whether formally or informally. It's fine to prefer other words, of course, but there is nothing wrong with *submit* for any objective reason that's been raised.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, @JimReynolds. The corpus of written English is overwhelmingly biased toward submitting a ***written*** thesis, but that would be expected, and measuring the spoken usage is not as straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

The word ***thesis*** has at least three different meanings.

1. - a statement of theory that is put forward as a premise to be maintained or proved: *his central thesis is that psychological life is not part of the material world.* (in Hegelian philosophy) a proposition forming the first stage in the process of dialectical reasoning. Compare with *antithesis, synthesis*.
2. - a long essay or dissertation involving personal research, written by a candidate for a university degree: *a doctoral thesis*.
3. - an unstressed syllable or part of a metrical foot in Greek or Latin verse. Often contrasted with *arsis*.
     (Oxford Dictionary Online)

Of all the suggestions the OP makes, most relate to the first meaning of *thesis* above. Only *present* or *submit* would seem applicable to the second meaning, namely *a doctoral thesis*.

Answer (score 3):

What I like about NGrams is they're great for idiomatic preference "beauty contests"...

[image: all]

But ***thesis*** has two common meanings. Both the big hitters in that chart *(submit, present)* are mainly for the "university degree component" sense. So if we exclude them we can focus on the remaining alternatives - which are far more likely to occur in general conversation/debate...

[image: rest]

The three clear front-runners there *(advance, put forward, argue)* all suggest "combative" championing of a position, which is what we'd expect in the non-academic context (where you're more likely to be quizzed and even challenged *back* by sceptics, in a debate).

I assume everyone agrees academia accounts for most of the *present, submit* usages. The main point of the pretty pictures is to show we use lots of different verbs in more everyday contexts (I could have added *expound, introduce*, etc., but it would just become unreadable).

TL;DR: You need to *push* your thesis *forward* a bit, but the exact word doesn't really matter.

Comment: This settles it. *propound* it is.

Answer (score -2):

I would vote for "present," or "advance."

Comment: Could you explain why? Can you provide any references which support your preference?